# The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: PATCH, DELETE

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I am trying to add a delete function to my application where there will be a list of inventory presented and you can delete an item if you wish. However, I don't know where I am going wrong since it does say delete is supported.

Here my my router:

```
Route::delete('/inventories/{inventory}', [\App\Http\Controllers\InventoryController::class, 'destroy'])->name('inventories.destroy');
```

Here is my controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Inventory;
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Illuminate\Routing\Redirector;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class InventoryController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\View
     */
    public function index(): \Illuminate\Contracts\View\View
    {
        $inventories = Inventory::all();
        return view('pages.inventories',[
            "inventories" => $inventories
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\View
     */
    public function create(): \Illuminate\Contracts\View\View
    {
        return view('pages.inventories.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @return Redirector
     */
    public function store(Request $request): Redirector
    {
        $validated = $request->validate([
            'title'=> 'required|string',
            'description'=> 'required|string|max:300',
            'price' => 'required|integer|min:0',
            'in_stock' => 'required|integer',
            'on_sale' => 'required|boolean'
        ]);
        $inventory = new Inventory();

        $inventory->fill($validated)->save();

        return redirect('/inventories');
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\View
     */
    public function edit(Inventory $inventory): \Illuminate\Contracts\View\View
    {
        return view('pages.inventories.edit',[
            "inventory" => $inventory
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @param Inventory $inventory
     * @return RedirectResponse
     * @throws ValidationException
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Inventory $inventory): RedirectResponse
    {
        $validated = $this->validate($request, [
            'title'=> 'required|string',
            'description'=> 'required|string|max:300',
            'price' => 'required|integer|min:0',
            'in_stock' => 'required|integer',
            'on_sale' => 'required|boolean'
        ]);
        $inventory->fill($validated)->save();
        return redirect()->route('inventories.index')->with('status',
            'Item has been updated!' . $inventory->title);
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  Inventory $inventory
     * @return RedirectResponse
     */
    public function destroy(Inventory $inventory): RedirectResponse
    {
        $inventory = Inventory::find($inventory);
        $inventory->delete();
        return redirect()->route('inventories.index')->with('status',
            'Item has been deleted!' . $inventory->title);
    }
}
```

Here is my delete.blade file:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title', 'Delete Inventory')

@section('content')
    <h1><strong>Delete inventory</strong></h1>
    <x-inventory-form :inventory=$inventory />
    {{ $inventory }}
    <form method="POST" action="{{url('/inventories',[$inventory->id])}}"></form>
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    @if ($errors->any())
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <ul>
                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
    @endif
@endsection
```

Here is my inventories.blade file:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title', 'My Inventory')

@section('content')
    <h1>Inventory Table</h1>
    <p>This is the inventory table made using PHP Laravel that is randomly generated.</p>
   <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>In stock</th>
                <th>On sale</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach($inventories as $inventory)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$inventory->id}}</td>
                <td>{{$inventory->title}}</td>
                <td>{{$inventory->description}}</td>
                <td> &pound;{{ number_format($inventory->price, 2) }}</td>
                <td>{{$inventory->in_stock}}</td>
                <td>{{ $inventory->on_sale ? 'Yes' : 'No' }}</td>
                <td><a href="{{ route('inventories.edit', $inventory) }}">Edit</a></td>
                <td><a href="{{ route('inventories.destroy', $inventory) }}">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
@endsection
```

Here is my inventory form component:

```
<?php

namespace App\View\Components;

use App\Models\Inventory;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
use Illuminate\View\Component;

class InventoryForm extends Component
{
    /**
     * @var Inventory|null
     */
    public $inventory;

    /**
     * @param Inventory|null $inventory
     */
    public function __construct(Inventory $inventory = null)
    {
        $this->inventory = $inventory;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function action(): string
    {
        if ($this->inventory) {
            return route('inventories.update', ['inventory' => $this->inventory]);
        }

        return route('inventories.store');
    }

    /**
     * Get the view / contents that represent the component.
     *
     *
     * @return View|\Closure|string
     */
    public function render()
    {
        return view('components.inventory-form');
    }
```

And here is my inventory form component blade file:

```
<form action="{{ $action }}" method="post">
    @if($inventory)
        @method('patch')
    @endif
    @csrf
    <label for="title">Enter an item name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="title" value="{{ $inventory?->title }}" required /><br><br>

    <label for="description">Enter the item's description:</label>
    <textarea name="description" required>{{ $inventory?->description }}</textarea><br><br>

    <label for="price">Enter the item's price:</label>
    <input type="number" name="price" value="{{ $inventory?->price }}" required/><br><br>

    <label for="in_stock">Enter a number of items in stock:</label>
    <input type="number" name="in_stock" value="{{ $inventory?->in_stock }}" required/><br><br>

    <label for="on_sale">Select yes/no if item is on sale:</label>
    <select name="on_sale" value="{{ (int) $inventory?->on_sale }}" required>
        <option value="" disabled {{ $inventory ? '' : 'selected' }}>--Please choose an option--</option>
        <option value="1" {{ $inventory?->on_sale ? 'selected' : '' }}>Yes</option>
        <option value="0" {{ (false === $inventory?->on_sale) ? 'selected' : '' }}>No</option>
    </select><br><br>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: I guess, your delete.blade file is wrapped in a form, right?

Comment: Yes I have an inventoryfrom class and a inventory-form blade file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my routes file I needed to write a get request with delete and a delete request with destroy. My new edited code is:

```
Route::get('/inventories/{inventory}/delete', [\App\Http\Controllers\InventoryController::class, 'delete'])->name('inventories.delete');

Route::delete('/inventories/{inventory}', [\App\Http\Controllers\InventoryController::class, 'destroy'])->name('inventories.destroy');
```

And my controller:

```
 /**
     * @param Inventory $inventory
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\View
     */
    public function delete(Inventory $inventory)
    {
        return view('pages.inventories.delete', ["inventory" => $inventory]);
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  Inventory $inventory
     * @return RedirectResponse
     */
    public function destroy(Inventory $inventory): RedirectResponse
    {
        $inventory->delete();
        return redirect()->route('inventories.index')->with('status',
            'Item has been deleted!');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your name is wrong `__method` it should `_method` only.

You may use blade directive instead.

```
@section('content')
<h1><strong>Delete inventory</strong></h1>
{{ $inventory }}
    @method('DELETE')
    @csrf
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
@endsection
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this for delete method.

```
@method('DELETE')
@csrf
```

**OR**

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete" />
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

If you are using laravel 5.*

```
{!! method_field('delete') !!}
{!! csrf_field() !!}
```

Comment: Hope it's work for you!..

Comment: Thank you! It does help in helping me understand but I still get the same error. :( I think it may be something with my blade file?

Answer (score 0):

To change the method used in a form, the attribute to use is `_method` not `__method`. Same thing for `_token`

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete">
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the

```
<form method="POST" action="{{url('/inventories',[$inventory->id])}}"></form>
```

so it is picking the current url as a get method. so adding the  should fix it.

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title', 'Delete Inventory')

@section('content')
    <h1><strong>Delete inventory</strong></h1>
    {{ $inventory }}
    <form method="POST" action="{{url('/inventories',[$inventory->id])}}"> 
        @method('delete')
        @csrf
    @if ($errors->any())
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <ul>
                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
    @endif
    </form>
@endsection
```